# Spin animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to spin an imageview , and I believe that the way I am doing is rather ugly . I am using a recursive method , to scale to max from min , when the min has been consequently reached.

Is there a better way to perform the spin ?

```
 private void spinLogo(boolean scaleUp)
{

    if(scaleUp) {
        mLogo.animate().scaleX(1f).setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator()).setDuration(200).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spinLogo(false);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        mMolLogo.animate().scaleX(0f).setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator()).setDuration(1000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                spinLogo(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The termination of this animation is not of my concern at the moment . This animation would run for maximum 5 seconds. This is actually attached to a launcher activity . And as soon as the sync webservice returns , i switch on to the main activity by destroying the launcher activity.

SO yes . any better ways to achieve the spin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an xml file in anim resource folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

Than in your activity or wherever you want create field `Animation scaling`

Initialize it with `scaling = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.scaling);`

Set animation with `view.startAnimation(scaling);`. To stop animation call `view.clearAnimation();`

Comment: this looks really pretty . I would test this and mark this answer in an hour .

Comment: hey . this is a rotate animation . if you see the sample code i posted , it is a scale animation . by Spin i mean to continously loop an image from scaleX 0 to scaleX 1 and back . This would give an effect like a coin spinning on  a surface. 

So i dont need a rotate animation . I need a scaleanimation that scales from 0 to 1 , and then 1 to 0 on X axis infinitely . Any pointers?